# two errors after starting the GNOME desktop 20.10

Tags: gnome, startup-applications, gnome-keyring, gnome-session, 20.10

Ｈi all
When the system boot is complete, there are two important error messages in ‘gome logs’.
“Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.”
Desktop environment and version.
OS : Ubuntu 20.10 - x86-64
GNOME Shell 3.38.1

```
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2151.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2151.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2149.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2149.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn gnome-keyring-daemon[1897]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn gnome-keyring-daemon[1897]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: ssh-agent.service: Succeeded.
Eki 27 23:17:25 YsnOnrAydn systemd[1882]: Starting GNOME Session Manager (session: ubuntu)...
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: You question mentions your OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, however you've tagged 20.10?   Please clarify?   (your GNOME version seems to imply 20.10)

Comment: My operating system is ubuntu 20.10.
I downloaded Ubuntu 20.10 and installed it from scratch.

Comment: Please correct (ie. *edit*) your question then, as it clearly states 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's an upstream bug as it's very similar to this one from Fedora : https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/two-errors-after-starting-the-gnome-desktop/9081

So I think it's safe to wait next Gnome update, maybe in Ubuntu 21.04.