# Failed to start app-gnome-gnome - boot - Bug since 2015

Tags: gnome, debian, fedora

Gnome has been malfunctioning for several years.
[image: gnome failed]
This does not handicap the use of its OS.
It appears on many Ubuntu Debian and Fedora platforms and on all versions of Gnome.
There are also recurring questions about this little problem.

Would you like to share a current or future solution?

Comment: identical or similar questions:

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287519/two-errors-after-starting-the-gnome-desktop-20-10

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a 23.04 LiveUSB "Try Ubuntu" environment?